# Desmarcar um checkbox ao clicar fora dele

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, layout-responsivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como é possivel desmarcar um checkbox caso eu clique em outro campo do site?

O checkbox serve para que quando o estado seja de 'checked', ele 'arraste' meu menu de -65% para 0 e apareça na tela, sendo utilizado em um layout mobile responsivo.

Infelizmente não tenho noção como isso pode ser feito, mas acredito que seja em javascript/jquery.

Ex:

```
<header id="menuCelular">
<input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
<label id="barra-icon-menu" for="btn-menu"><label id="txt-menu" for="btn-menu">Menu</label></label>

<nav class="menuMobile">
<ul class="menu">

      <li id="mapa-menu" class="abre-dropdown"><a href="\\">Mapa do site</a>
        <ul class="submenu-1">
            <li><a href="\\">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="\\">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="\\">link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>    
   <li class="abre-dropdown"><a href="\\">>Aprendizado</a>
        <ul class="submenu-1">
            <li><a href="\\">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="\\">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="\\">link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="textos-menu"><a href="\\" title="\\">Textos</a></li>    
    <li class="fotos-menu"><a href="\\" title="\\"></label>Fotos</a></li> 

</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Agora, quando o menu está aberto, se eu clicar barra #menuCelular ele não fecha, a não ser que eu aperte fora da região do .menuMobile

[SITE (Redimensione o viewport para 479px)](http://tucobracoral.xyz/nossa-casa)

Comment: Tentou o método `$.blur` da jquery, acho que adicionando ele no checkbox e atribuindo uma função funcione

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo? Nunca utilizei do método.

Comment: Provavelmente o checkbox não é a melhor solução neste caso. Seria melhor algo relacionado ao foco, ou mesmo links para fragmento ( `#` ) + css.

Comment: Sim, eu imaginei. Acontece que foi o primeiro menu responsivo que eu fiz,  então fiquei meio confuso em relação a tudo isso, é novo pra mim. Irei editar e deixar o site para que deem uma olhada. Caso acessem, redimensionem o navegador para ver a versão mobile (479px).

Comment: @ThiagoBarros o checkbox escondido é bem interessante para coisas com comportamento _toggle_ (liga / desliga), mas é que justo no seu caso, seria mais relacionado ao foco mesmo. Mas é bom saber usar css + check, dá pra fazer umas coisas mais complexas.

Comment: Sim, eu aprendi o metodo com umas video aulas do youtube. Enfim.. não é possivel fazer a seguinte estrutura: Imagine que o checkbox foi marcado, então: Caso o usuario aperte em alguma regiao fora do menu que foi aberto com o proprio checkbox, o mesmo é desmarcado, e automaticamente o menu desaparece, pois ele só aberto caso o checkbox esteja marcado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bem caso deseje mesmo utilizar o `checkBox`, você pode fazer assim:

```js
var checkbox = $('#button-menu');

$('body').not('#menu').click(function() {
  checkbox.prop("checked", false);
});

$('#button-menu, #menu').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();

});
```

```css
#geral {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
}

#menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="geral">
  <input type="checkbox" id="button-menu">
  <nav id="menu">
    Clique fora dessa div

  </nav>
</div>
```

Usei o [`.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). Basicamente, ao clicar em qualquer lugar no `body` você irá fazer com que o `checkbox` seja desmarcado, contudo, caso clique ou no checkbox ou na `div#menu` a propagação do evento que faz a desmarcação deixará de acontecer, assim poderá haver a marcação.

Esse método é bem poderoso então tenha cuidado ao aplicá-lo. Veja aqui - https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Porém, agora ocorreu outro problema: Quando eu clico na barra para fechar o menu ela não funciona mais, e o menu só se fecha caso eu clique fora da região.

Comment: Não sei se fui claro, caso necessite, eu posso explicar de outra forma @Samir

Comment: Você possui uma função isolada para fechar o menu? Caso possua tente aplicá-la após o `.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Não, ele funciona junto com o checkbox: quando 'checked' o menu desliza de -65% pra 0 (o menu fica escondido no canto da tela), e quando desmarcado ele volta pra -65%.

Comment: Você pode me mostrar essa parte do seu código, acho que sei qual o problema.

Comment: Mostro assim. Prefere que eu coloque no comentario ou edite a pergunta? Alias, caso ache necessário, eu desfaço todo esse evento de checkbox e refaço o evento onclick, apesar de que não faço ideia de como.

Comment: Isso que eu estava pensando. Acho melhor editar a resposta, ficar melhor para visualizar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33596/discussion-between-thiago-barros-and-samir-braga). EDITEI a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando a resposta e o link oferecido por @SamirBraga, segue abaixo código sem utilizar o `event.stopPropagation();`

```js
var checkbox = $('#button-menu');

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('#button-menu, #menu').length) {
    checkbox.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```css
#geral {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
}

#menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="geral">
  <input type="checkbox" id="button-menu">
  <nav id="menu">
    Clique fora dessa div

  </nav>
</div>
```

O exemplo foi retirado do [próprio link](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) sobre os perigos de se utilizar o `stopPropagation`, que segundo o mesmo deve ser utilizado apenas quando se deseja realmente cancelar um evento da arvore DOM, como por exemplo a submissão de um formulário.

> Stopping propagation should be thought of like canceling an event, and
>   it should only be used with that intent. Perhaps you want to prevent a
>   form submission or disallow focus to an area of the page. In these
>   cases you're stopping propagation because you don't want an event to
>   happen, not because you have an unwanted event handler registered
>   higher up in the DOM.

Comment: Perfeito! obrigado, espero que ajude outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
$("#geral").not("#menu, #barra-icon-menu").click(function(){
    $("#button-menu").prop("checked", false);
    $("#barra-icon-menu").click();
});
```

Comment: Eu testei e continuo da mesma forma. Toda aquela barra azul da imagem abre o menu, pois é um label com o for direcionado para o checkbox, e quando pressionado altera as propriedades css e arrasta o menu para a tela.

Comment: Essa barra azul tem id classe? se tiver me passe que melhoro minha resposta e tentamos outra coisa

Comment: Irei estar passando a estrutura na pergunta, tudo bem? Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!