# Como decidir qual e como realizar a estrutura do css de um menu responsivo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Queria saber como vocês criam menus responsivos, qual a melhor estrutura em sua opinião tanto pro `html` quanto pro `css`, e se usam ou não o `javascript`.

pode ser tanto um menu próprio do usuário quando logado, quanto um menu para sites sem necessidade de login

:D grato

*Acredito que muita gente quando inicia nessa parte tem a mesma dúvida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isso, como é de se esperar, vai depender muito de seu site. A proposta dele, o design em geral, o código, que frameworks usas, entre outros.

#### HTML & CSS (only)

Você pode fazer um menu bem simples, clean, responsivo, com apenas html e css. Claro, nesse caso você com certeza usaria um [*Media Queria*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) e definiria breakpoints para suporte mobile. Os *breakpoints* mais famosos são os presentes nessa imagem:

[image: Famous Breakpoints]

Dessa forma você adapta o menu, e o resto do site, sem a necessidade de criar novos layouts, nem de usar javascript com essa finalidade.

Segue um exemplo bem simples dessa utilização:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 0;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.topBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px -2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px -2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 5px -2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
}

.topBar .content {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  background: #fff;
  background-size: auto 8px;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topBar .content .logo {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
}

.topBar .content .menu ul {
  display: block;
}

.topBar .content .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.1s ease;
  -moz-transition: border 0.1s ease;
  transition: border 0.1s ease;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topBar .content .menu .menu-icon {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 9px;
}
.topBar .content .menu .menu-icon span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #506967;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.topBar .content .menu input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.topBar .content .menu ul {
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.topBar .content .menu label {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.topBar .content .menu ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 3px #008c83;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .topBar .content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topBar .content .menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    height: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.2s ease;
    transition: height 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  .topBar .content .menu ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .topBar .content .menu .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .topBar .content .menu input:checked + ul {
    display: block;
    height: 270px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="/">
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </a>
    <nav class="menu">
      <label for="menu-check">
        <div class="menu-icon">
          <span class="menu-icon-line"></span>
          <br>
          <span class="menu-icon-line"></span>
          <br>
          <span class="menu-icon-line"></span>
        </div>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="menu-check">
      <ul>
        <li>Assuntos</li>
        <li>Tutoriais</li>
        <li>Contato</li>
        <li>Sobre</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Clique em página toda e mude o tamanho de sua janela.

No exemplo, uso o breakpoint:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { ...
```

A partir daí o menu se torna retrátil. Uma técnica bastante comum, mas que é funcional.

Ao analisar o código acima, você pode perceber o uso do `display: flex`. Apenas a nível de curiosidade, [**neste link**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), você pode ver um guia completo da utilização deste.

---

As outras possibilidades são muito subjetivas, principalmente em relação a implementação do javascript. Você pode usar para efeitos e transições com o JQuery, ou para adicionar funções no clique do ícone do menu, ou para um simples função de *clickout* para o menu desaparecer, como você pode ver [nessa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105992/desmarcar-um-checkbox-ao-clicar-fora-dele/106010#106010).

Vou deixar [este link](http://exisweb.net/incredibly-useful-list-of-responsive-navigation-and-menu-patterns), com vários exemplos de menus responsivos, lá você tem acesso ao link de cada um deles. É bom para "se inspirar".

Espero ter ajudado.